# latex error lonely item--perhaps a missing list environment in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, errors

I'm using the `thebibliography` environment for listing the references in  a `report` LaTeX file.

This error appear in each `\bibitem` sentence

```
\begin{thebibliography}

\bibitem {Cluster}
\textbf{http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cluster}
\bibitem {install}
\textbf{https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Building\_a\_Beowulf\_Cluster}


\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're missing the mandatory argument to `\begin{thebibliography}`. In your case it should be `\begin{thebibliography}{9}` (any one digit number is good). Use `99` if you have more than nine items. It's also better to have a blank line after every item.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the mandatory argument to `\begin{thebibliography}`. In your case it should be

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
```

(any one digit number is good). Use 99 if you have more than nine items.

It's also better to have a blank line after every item.

See also [Argument in "thebibliography"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198330/argument-in-thebibliography) for other information about the problem.

---

A better way to input your bibliography would be

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem {Cluster}
\url{http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cluster}

\bibitem {install}
\url{https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Building_a_Beowulf_Cluster}

\end{thebibliography}
```

For the `\url` command you need to load the `url` package

```
\usepackage{url}
```

It is available also if you load `hyperref`. Note that in the second URL the underscores need not to be escaped.

Comment: when i use \usepackage{url} it's  compilation  give emergency stop error .is there any condition to use this package

Comment: @sepeee Sorry, but the information is insufficient. Please try making a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and open a new question.