# Lonely item error in bibliography .bbl file

Tags: bibtex, citing, bibentry

I want to create a `.bbl` file with bibitems to be able to use it with `bibentry` package. Below is a single example how I'm doing this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{ABC} Author Name {\em Title} 2016.

\end{the bibliography}
```

In my `testFile.tex` file I attached the `testFile.bbl` file as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}
 \input{testFile.bbl}
 \bibliographystyle{alpha}
 \nobibliography{testFile}

 My citation: \cite{ABC}
\end{document}
```

However, when I run my `.tex` file I obtain the following error:

```
Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.
```

I checked that solution
[latex error lonely item--perhaps a missing list environment in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243741/latex-error-lonely-item-perhaps-a-missing-list-environment-in-the-bibliography)
, but it is not working unfortunately. I'm using TexShop for Mac's, however I tried also to compile via terminal and the error was the same. Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the appearance of `bibliographystyle` and `nobiliography` in your code. Why is it in there?

Comment: @Johannes_B nobiliography is because even if I want to cite, I don't want to have the list of references at the end of the file. bibliography style is to define the style, shouldn't it be there?

Comment: The `\nobibliography{testFile}` in not needed, beside this your example works fine. Are you sure that you are really running exactly what you are showing? And how is the name of your main document? Can you show the log-file?

Comment: @The name of my main document is the same as the bibliography file (testFile.tex)

Comment: Hm. Dangerous. If you click once on bibtex you can overwrite your manual bbl.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, so I should make a different name for my bbl file?

Comment: I ran into the same problem by switching from an old working latex source to xelatex. Are you by any chance running  xelatex?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
```

instead of just

```
\usepackage{bibentry}
```

fixed the `Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment` error in the auto-generated `.bbl` file when using the `\nobibliography{testFile}` option.