# underfull \hbox (badness 4765) in paragraph at lines 22-23

Tags: badness

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}


\title{Annotated Bibliography}
\author{ffhjn}
\date{April 2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Aim}
amvfnurgii

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{Cornell University Library}
\url{http://guides.library.cornell.edu/annotatedbibliography}. Accessed on 18 April 2017.

\bibitem{USC Libraries}
\url{http://libguides.usc.edu/writingguide/annotatedbibliography}. Accessed on 18 April 2017.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! Please provide a complete description of your error, not just the code.

Comment: Also, from what I understand you are wondering why you are getting the BadBox message. You are using `{99}` while only using a single digit number of references, 2 in this case, but this should not prevent your `.tex` file from compiling. Look here to see what he arguments in `thebibliography` should be for your case specifically: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198330/argument-in-thebibliography

Answer (score 2):

the badness is a measure of how over stretched the line is. 4765 isn't impossibly bad, although it's not great.

[image]

As you can see the first "Accessed on 18" is stretched out.

With such small paragraphs with large unbreakable units there is not a lot you can do, you could just accept it stretches or set it ragged right:

[image]

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\raggedright

\bibitem{Cornell University Library}
\url{http://guides.library.cornell.edu/annotatedbibliography}. Accessed on 18 April 2017.

\bibitem{USC Libraries}
\url{http://libguides.usc.edu/writingguide/annotatedbibliography}. Accessed on 18 April 2017.

\end{thebibliography}
```