# Omit the section references

Tags: bibliographies

With the following codes

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\frenchspacing
\sectionfont{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
  \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section*{Papers}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
 \bibitem{as1} {J. Agler, M. Stankus,} {$m$-Isometric transformations of Hilbert space $I$}, Integral Equations Operator Theory 21 (1995) 383-429.

\bibitem{as2} {J. Agler, M. Stankus,} {$m$-Isometric transformations of Hilbert space $II$}, Integral Equations Operator Theory 21 (1995) 383-429.

\bibitem{as3} {J. Agler, M. Stankus,} {$m$-Isometric transformations of Hilbert space $III$}, Integral Equations Operator Theory 21 (1995) 383-429.

 \end{thebibliography}
```

\end{document}

I get
[image]

However I want to obtain

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest not to use an extra `\section*{...}`. Instead, redefine the References header (in the preamble) according to the document class:

- `\renewcommand{\refname}{Papers}` for the class `article`;
- `\renewcommand{\bibname}{Papers}` for the classes `book` and `report`.

Using the first option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\frenchspacing
\sectionfont{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
  \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Papers}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
 \bibitem{as1} {J. Agler, M. Stankus,} {$m$-Isometric transformations of Hilbert space $I$}, Integral Equations Operator Theory 21 (1995) 383-429.

\bibitem{as2} {J. Agler, M. Stankus,} {$m$-Isometric transformations of Hilbert space $II$}, Integral Equations Operator Theory 21 (1995) 383-429.

\bibitem{as3} {J. Agler, M. Stankus,} {$m$-Isometric transformations of Hilbert space $III$}, Integral Equations Operator Theory 21 (1995) 383-429.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but why you replace `\begin{thebibliography}{999}` by `\begin{thebibliography}{9}`?

Comment: @Schüler I don't understand. Your code initially had `\begin{thebibliography}{9}`, and I haven't changed it. Where have you noticed `\begin{thebibliography}{999}`?

Comment: Yes yes sorry, because in my original file I have \begin{thebibliography}{999}. Is there a difference? Thanks.

Comment: @Schüler Yes, there is a difference. This is a so-called *wlab*, or *widest label* argument. In theory, you can omit it; if you want to know more, I think the thread [Argument in “thebibliography”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198330/argument-in-thebibliography) would be useful.

Comment: @Schüler No prob:)