# Bibliography: latex error something's wrong--perhaps a missing item

Tags: bibliographies, errors

I got always the error "latex error something's wrong--perhaps a missing item" in the two first items of my bibliography. In the output, the first item is not taken and the second one has two reference as you can see on this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

This is a code snap of the bibliography:

```
\phantomsection              
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname} 
\bibliographystyle{bib/bmc-mathphys}  
\begin{thebibliography}
\bibitem{b1} ..... 
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `thebibliography` environment takes an argument. Try `\begin{thebibliography}{99}`. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198330/134574. _Off-topic_: `\bibliographystyle` does nothing if you are writing the bibliographies manually.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It works !!! Many many thanks :))))